# Uniform limits of derivative of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, cauchy-integral-formula

I want to prove the following theorem:

*Let $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ be a sequence of analytic functions on an open $U$, converging uniformly on every compact subset $K$ of $U$ to a function $f$. Then $f$ is holomorphic. Moreover, the sequence of derivatives $\lbrace f'_n \rbrace$ converges uniformly on every compact subset $K$, and $\lim f'_n = f'$.*

The book of Serge Lang (Complex Analysis) gives the proof of the first part (that $f$ is holomorphic), and I understand this part. Now I have tried showing the second part myself, using the hint from the book, which says: "Cover the compact set with a finite number of closed discs contained in $U$, and of sufficiently small radius. Cauchy's formula expresses the derivatives $f'_n$ as an integral, and one can argue as in the previous theorem."

With this hint, I came to the following proof:

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $U$. Let $r>0$ be such that $\forall z \in K$, $\bar{D}(z,r)$ is contained in $U$. We note that $\mathcal{U} := \lbrace D(z,r/2) \ | \ z \in K \rbrace$ is an open cover of $K$: 
$K \subseteq \cup_{z \in K} D(z,r/2)$. Because $K$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering, and we see that

$K \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{m} D(z_i,r/2) \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{m} \bar{D}(z_i,r/2) =: M$,

where $z_i \in K$ for $i=1,...,m$. Pick one of these $z_i$. We know that $f_n$ is analytic on $U$ for all $n$, and the same is true for the limit function $f$. So certainly they are both analytic on $\bar{D}(z_i,r)$. Then by a corollary of Cauchy's formula, we find that for $z \in \bar{D}(z_i,r/2)$,

$|f'_n(z) - f'(z)| \leq \frac{r}{(r/2)^2} \| f_n - f \|_{C_r} = \frac{4}{r} \| f_n - f \|_{C_r}$,

where $\| f_n - f \|_{C_r}$ is the sup norm of $f_n - f$ on the circle of radius $r$. This circle is closed and bounded, hence compact, so $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ here. Therefore, we find that the estimate above goes to zero for $n \to \infty$. Hence $f'_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on $\bar{D}(z_i,r/2)$. Because this is true for every $z_i$, $i=1,...,m$, we see that $f'_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on all of $M$. Because $K$ is contained in $M$, we can conclude that $f'_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on $K$, for every compact $K$. $\square$

This seems like a correct proof to me, but I am not sure, mostly because the hint said explicitly to cover $K$ with a *finite* number of closed discs, and I have nowhere used this fact (the finite subcover).

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It meant that if $|z-a| < r$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $|s-a| \le r$ then $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a| = r} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds, \qquad f'(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a| = r} \frac{f(s)}{(s-z)^2}ds$$ and the fact $f_n \to f$ converges uniformly on $|s-a| \le r$ does the trick

Comment: I understand this. However, I have not used it explicitly in my proof; is the proof correct, or is there anything really wrong with it?

Comment: You mentioned a "corollary of the Cauchy's integral formula". Why don't you use the Cauchy's integral formula directly ?

Comment: I tried that as well - in the end, I made an estimate which led to the same result as directly using the corollary, so it did not really make a difference (at least not the way I used it).

Comment: It makes a difference when you are sure about something, and when you are not. If $f_n-f$ is holomorphic on $|s-a| \le r$ and $|f_n- f| \le C$ and $|z-a| < r$ then $$|f_n'(z)-f_n(z)| = | \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|s-a| = r} \frac{f_n(s)-f(s)}{(s-z)^2}ds| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|s-a| = r} \frac{|f_n(s)-f(s)|}{|s-z|^2}d|s| \\ \le  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{|s-a| = r} \frac{C}{(r - |z-a|)^2}d|s|=\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{2 \pi r C}{(r - |z-a|)^2}$$

Comment: For future visitors, this theorem appears as Thm. 36 in Terry Tao's 246A Notes 3 https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/math-246a-notes-3-cauchys-theorem-and-its-consequences/#unf